# Optimization reading images from disk python

Tags: python, image, memory, optimization

I wonder what is faster and better:

```python
class AvgRGB(object):

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

        self.imgs = []
        self.avg = MyRGBImg()       

    def gather_pictures(self):
        # for now gathe all the files, next check for picture extensions
        p = self.path
        self.names = [f for f in listdir(p) if isfile(join(p, f))]

        for imgname in self.names:
            path, name, ext = get_pathname(imgname)
            if ext in ['.png', '.jpg']:
                imagepath = join(self.path, imgname)
                img = MyRGBImg(imagepath )
                self.imgs.append(img)

    def average(self):
        dataset = self.imgs

        s = MyRGBImg(np.zeros(dataset[0].data.shape))
        for i, picture in enumerate(dataset):
            im = picture.data
            s += im 

        s = s / float(len(dataset))
        self.avg = MyRGBImg(s)
```

or

```python
class AvgRGB_savememory(object):

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        self.imgs_names = []

    def get_image(self, index):
        # read the image corresponding to the path
        pathtopic = join(self.path, self.imgs_names[index])
        myimg = MyRGBImg()
        myimg.read_from_file(pathtopic)
        return myimg

    def gather_pictures_names(self):
        p = self.path
        filenames = [f for f in listdir(p) if isfile(join(p, f))]
        for filename in filenames:
            path, name, ext = get_pathname(filename)
            if ext in ['.png', '.jpg']:       
                self.imgs_names.append(filename)

    def average(self, aligned = True, debug = False):
        sizedataset = len(self.imgs_names)
        picture = self.get_image(0)       

        s = MyRGBImg(np.zeros(picture.data.shape)) 
        for i in range(sizedataset):
            #load the picture
            picture = self.get_image(i)
            im = picture.data
            #perform operations
            s += im 

        s = s / float(sizedataset)
        self.avg = MyRGBImg(s)
```

This snipplet of code takes images from a folder and averages them.

The difference between the two snipplets are: the first loads the images in an array while the second loads the picture from memory.

Now you have to imagine this is not the only operation I do, and the program gives memory error when I try to analyze data from 500 pictures (1080x1080x3).

My question is which is better? or faster?

In theory the first should be faster because loads all the images in the memory, yet what happens when the size of the array are bigger than the RAM? they get written on the disk? and if that is so isnt that slower than just reading the single images?
Moreover would streaming the pictures from buffer more effective considering all my procedures are sequential?

Comment: Why not just profile your code?

Comment: I was thinking about a theoretical answer... I know by hand the second way is illogically faster because it doesnt clog the memory, which if im using chrome to browse stackoverflow is... a precious resource

Comment: Theory is grounded in data. Experiment with it for yourself, then determine why you see what you do.

Comment: Well... This is unsettling. I mean I hoped I wasnt the first running in this kind of problem. Like there's so many option to test (load save data in binary, load save data in png format (less data to write vs more calculations), and so on) but the thing is I'm sure theres a clever way to estimate these processes. Or instruct a conditional -> if total image size > x use the save memory option else use the load in memory

Comment: I posted what you said

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your sample data, but I'll use some dummy function and arg. You can find out the actual cost of a given function call by call like so:

```
your_function = lambda x: enumerate(range(x, x**x))
your_arg1 = 8
import cProfile
import pstats
prof = cProfile.Profile()
group = prof.runcall(your_function, your_arg1)
p = pstats.Stats(prof)
p.sort_stats('time').print_stats(100)
```

This will print out e.g.:

```
   3 function calls in 0.600 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.600    0.600    0.600    0.600 {range}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.600    0.600 python.py:1(<lambda>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Comment: I would like a more theoretical approach. I mean i know the second method is faster and doesnt give a `Memory error`, yet goes against to all what I learned abour RAM and ROM

Answer (score 0):

As suggested I made some homemade profiling

I used this self implemented timing function
https://pastebin.com/Myph3ndJ

and here are the two tested functions `AvgFolder` and `AvgFolderMem`, the first one loads all the images in memory, while the second loads the images from the disk when needed. Here are the implementation of the
https://github.com/Pella86/DenoiseAverage/blob/master/src/AvgFolder_class.py

These are the results summarized:
https://pastebin.com/pcHZFVLV

**5 pictures 128x128 (gray scale)**

```
--------LOAD IN MEM 5---------
Total elapsed time: 00:00:05
305 us/px
--------MEMSAVE 5---------
Total elapsed time: 00:00:06
366 us/px
```

**20 pictures 128x128 (gray scale)**

```
--------LOAD IN MEM 20---------
Total elapsed time: 00:00:20
1220 us/px
--------MEMSAVE 20 ---------
Total elapsed time: 00:00:20
1220 us/px
```

**100 pictures 128x128 (gray scale)**

```
--------LOAD IN MEM 100---------
Total elapsed time: 00:01:37
5920 us/px
--------MEMSAVE 100---------
Total elapsed time: 00:01:46
6469 us/px
```

**20 pictures 512x512 (gray scale)**

```
--------LOAD IN MEM---------
Total elapsed time: 00:27:26
100'463 us/px
--------MEMSAVE---------
Total elapsed time: 00:27:40
101'310 us/px
```

Thus contrary to text book notions, loading files up and down from disk memory with numpy can be pretty efficient.
I have no idea if is because the images get into paging problems or because my RAM is full of crap.